# Do I need to set uid bit in this case?

Tags: permissions, x11, setuid, setgid

I have modified xlockmore source to add a feature I needed, but it is unable to read the shadow password file and is asking me to set uid or gid bit on the binary. But the official binary I use doesn't have any of it's sticky bit set. Is there a workaround to avoid setting the special bits?
Also, the custom binaries are more than twice the size of official ones, even though I haven't modified them much.

Answer (score 2):

The official 'pkgdir'  gives '--disable-setuid' as an option to the 'configure' script, which creates the makefile according to the compilation environment. Compiling the source according to pkgdir resolved the problem.